# Handling Sending Two Parameters in an API Call in Angular App

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular, mongoose, angular2-observables

I have a series of filter functions that allow a user to click on a series of filters in order to filter data displaying in a grid view. I have the filters working using observables when I build them using an individual function for each filter. We are using a kind of query built into mongoose that lets you pass a specific query by field in the body of a post call. I am using it like this:

```
    onFilterReceived(language) {
        if (language) {
            this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
                "services.workflow.status" : "consulting",
                "languages.primary" : { $in: language },
                })
                .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                    this.records = resRecordsData;
                    console.log('onFilterReceived: ' + language);
                },
                responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
        } else {
            this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
                "services.workflow.status" : "consulting"
            })
                .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                    this.records = resRecordsData;
                },
                responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
     }
```

My service function, being called here, looks like this:

```
getByFilter(page, pagesize, body) {
    const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
    return this.http.post
    (`https://api.someurl.com/${this.ver}/customers/search?apikey=${this.key}&page=${page}&pagesize=${pagesize}`,
    body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .catch(this.filterErrorHandler);
}
    filterErrorHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

This works as is.

However, what I want to be able to do is handle passing multiple key/value pairs, not just one.

You'll also notice that I am checking to only run the request *if* language exists - that is to say, if a language input has been sent via a filter click. This is necessary because otherwise the function errors out when querying the api because there is no value.

To handle two filters at a time, I tried doing this:

```
onFilterReceived(language, nationality) {
    // Receive filter selections for language
    if (language) {
        this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "services.workflow.status" : "consulting",
            "languages.primary" : { $in: language },
            })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                console.log('onFilterReceived: ' + language);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
    } 

    // Receive filter selections for nationality
    if (nationality) {
        this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
            "services.workflow.status" : "consulting",
            "services.service" : { $in: nationality },
            })
            .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                this.records = resRecordsData;
                console.log('onFilterReceived: ' + nationality);
            },
            responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError);
     }     
}
```

But this didn't work. While I am passing in two fields/values in the above:

```
        "languages.primary" : { $in: language },
```

And in the other one:

```
        "services.service" : { $in: nationality },
```

... the function doesn't work properly.

To clarify, if the "language" filter is clicked, I want to send the request on "language". But if the "nationality" filter is clicked, I want to send the request on "nationality".

But I also want to not lose one parameter in exchange for the other. In other words, if "spanish" is clicked on the "language" filter, I want that to "stick". Then when "American" is clicked from the "nationality" filter, I want the request to filter by BOTH of those parameters, not lose one in exchange for the other. How could I re-work this function to handle this?

By the way, events/values are being received from another component via Output() and EventEmitter(). The view looks like this:

```
        <list [records]="records" 
            (sendLanguage)="onFilterReceived($event)"
            (sendNationality)="onFilterReceived($event)">
        </list>
```

And the html for my filters looks like this:

```
       <filter-option name="Language"
                        placeholder="Select Language"
                        [usePlaceholder]="!languageFilters.text"
                        [visible]="languageFilters.enabled">
            <filter-label>{{languageFilters.text}}</filter-label>
            <filter-menu>
                <div class="visit-type-filter-options">
                    <md-checkbox *ngFor="let option of languageFilters.options" [(ngModel)]="option.value">
                        {{option.language}}
                    </md-checkbox>
                </div>
            </filter-menu>
        </filter-option>

        <!--NATIONALITY-->
        <filter-option name="Nationality"
                        placeholder="Select Nationality"
                        [usePlaceholder]="!nationalityFilters.text"
                        [visible]="nationalityFilters.enabled">
            <filter-label>{{nationalityFilters.text}}</filter-label>
            <filter-menu>
                <div class="visit-type-filter-options">
                    <md-checkbox *ngFor="let option of nationalityFilters.options" [(ngModel)]="option.value">
                        {{option.nationality}}
                    </md-checkbox>
                </div>
            </filter-menu>
        </filter-option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the code neat. This will handle multiple parameters.

```
onFilterReceived(para: any, type: string) {
    let body:any = {};
    body['services.workflow.status'] = 'consulting';
    if (type == 'lan')
        body['languages.primary'] =  { $in: para };
    if (type == 'nat')
        body['services.service'] =  { $in: para };

    this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, body)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                       this.records = resRecordsData;
                   },
                   responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError
        );
}
```

In template:

```
<list [records]="records" 
    (sendLanguage)="onFilterReceived($event, 'lan')"
    (sendNationality)="onFilterReceived($event, 'nat')">
</list>
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, the value has to match with the field. So "nationality" would go on a different line, and be for the "services.service" field, not for "languages. primary". Those are like key/value pairs:
"languages.primary" : { $in: language },

Comment: I like how the succinctness of how you're suggesting handling this in the second half of your answer. But the stringifying doesn't seem necessary, nor is it working when I try it.

Comment: Can you debug on the service side? To check if paras have sent correctly? If not, are there any errors in browser console?

Comment: With the stringily, when I click the filters, the data no longer responds (whereas it does without the stringily), and in the console I'm getting "NaN": onFilterReceived: Spanish NaN

Comment: I double checked source code of Angular. It's not necessary. My fault. To debug this, can you output body in console? If the requests is fine, could you check if that is expected to be sent to server side?

Comment: When I console.log "body" I get:
Object {services.workflow.status: "consulting", languages.primary: Object}
languages.primary
:
Object
$in
:
Array(2)
0
:
"English"
1
:
"Spanish"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
__proto__
:
Object
services.workflow.status
:
"consulting"
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: That's with both "English" and "Spanish" selected on my language filter. But my second filter doesn't seem to show up in the body log here.

Comment: Now, I see. You need to give more details of your 'list' component.

Comment: <list [records]="records" 
            (sendLanguage)="onFilterReceived($event)"
            (sendNationality)="onFilterReceived($event)">
        </list>, but onFilterReceived(language, nationality) has two, that is why you cannot get the second parameter. I need to see more details to understand how you use EventEmitter(). Something must be wrong here.

Comment: It's actually only one parameter per function. I have changed it in the code above to reflect what I have. I was just putting in two parameters to prep what I wanted to do. The question is, how can I pass in multiple field/value pairs? As I mentioned earlier, I have it working when it's one key/value pair passed in a function. If the "language' selection is "French" and "English", I am handling that. But I want to be able to handle when more than one filter is selected - so that the data filters for BOTH "language" and "nationality", etc.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Just to clarify, what does "para" refer to?

Comment: para is same as your old 'language'. Looks like you are using $event shared in the two. Hence, you need another parameter 'type' to differentiate between them.

Comment: Thanks. This is close. I made an adjustment to the code above in my original function - because I need to also handle when a user de-selects a filter. Otherwise, that causes a 500 error from the API. The way I had been doing that was with an if/else. Only if "language" existed, for instance, would I send a new value for language. If "language" didn't exist, i.e., none of the language filters had been clicked, it would send a request without that field. So I need to work that conditional check in here too. If you look at my first function above (which I edited) you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I've got the conditional stuff working. But one issue, right now the function doesn't seem to adequately keep track of the right type. When I console log for language and type, and then nationality and type, BOTH show 'lan' - which is wrong:
onFilterReceived nat: undefined type: lan
onFilterReceived lang: Spanish type: lan

Comment: I think the answer may be to be more explicit about types in the template view.