# Building an API Call Holding Multiple Filter-selected Values in Angular App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventemitter

I have a series of checkbox filters in my Angular app, that when clicked on by a user in the view, should trigger functionality that queries the API to return filtered results. I have these filters working when used one at a time. However, I'm having difficulty figuring out how to structure the function so that it can hold ALL currently selected filters. The function call makes use of a Mongoose/MongoDB feature that lets us pass key/value pairs that correspond to fields directly into the payload of a post request.

This is what I initially had (that works, but only by handling one filter at a time via if/else statements). It basically says, if the "type" is of "lan", then assign value accordingly. And if no value is provided (i.e. the user has de-selected all filters), then just send an API call request without including any inputed parameters (the last "else" here):

```
    onFilterReceived(value, type) {
        if (type === 'lan' && value) {
            this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
                "services.workflow.status" : "consulting",
                "languages.primary" : { $in: value }
                });
        } else if (type === 'zip' && value) {
            this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
                "services.workflow.status" : "consulting",
                "zipCode" : { $in: value }
                });
        } else {
            this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, {
                "services.workflow.status" : "consulting"
            });
    }
```

I am getting both "value" and the corresponding "type" sent via Angular's Output() and EventEmitter(), like this:

```
        <list [records]="records"
            (sendLanguage)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'lan')"
            (sendZipcode)="onFilterReceived($event, type = 'zip')">
        </list>
```

Again, all of the above works *as is*.

However, what I'm trying to do is build this function is such a way that, when the value received is of type "lan", that the corresponding "value" in that case is applied to "value" here:

```
"languages.primary" : { $in: value }
```

And then when the value received has a corresponding type of "zip", that "value" is then applied to "value" here:

```
"zipCode" : { $in: value }
```

The end goal being that I will be able to send a request over the API that holds the values of multiple filters AT THE SAME TIME.

I've tried numerous formulations, but so far have been unable to get this to work as desired. I've been using 'if/else' statements, like above, but again, that will only allow me to hold a value from one filter at a time. How could I make sure I'm passing each of the currently selected filter values?

If someone could provide even a basic example of how to formulate this kind of logic, it'd be very helpful.

Comment: This is odd. I saw the same method name and requirement in one of my answered question. Is this a college assignment? And I saw your comment. What do you want further?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43769276/handling-sending-two-parameters-in-an-api-call-in-angular-app/43769985#43769985

Comment: No, this isn't a college assignment. Just something I'm working on. I wasn't able to get it working with your previous answer. I will review what you wrote again now and let you know what the gap was.

Comment: I remember now. I just tried plugging it in the way your answer suggested. The problem is, I'm still only able to process one filter at a time that way. I'm only getting the most recent filter applied. Not all applied filters. When I look at the payload in the network tab, it's just the most recent filter value being sent. In that sense, it doesn't get me any further ahead than what I have above. Have any idea how to resolve this so I can pass ALL currently selected filters?

Comment: It sounds like your binding method is just for setting a new filter rather than posting it to server, right? Then you need to change the code to support it. When will you send filters to server? You cannot do this in 'onFilterReceived' as firing any of them will trigger data posting,

Comment: I want to send the filters to the server every time there is a change (whether a new filter option is selected, or a filter option is deselected). The API call needs to go out on every change so filters can be stacked and unstacked based on user clicks on the filter checkboxes. Can you give me an idea of how to handle this?

Comment: Also, the code I have above does trigger the API call on every selection. That's working. And it can handle multiple options selected and deselected within ONE filter - like if "English" and "Spanish" are selected for "language" - that works, because this Mongoose setup accepts an array. But as currently constructed it cannot handle multiple filters. It only handles one filter at a time because of the if/else nature of the function. So I need to rethink that aspect of it. Open to suggestions. :)

Comment: See my code and let's discuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body: any = {'services.workflow.status':'consulting'};

private processType(name: string, para: any) {
    if (this.body[name]) // toggle filter, removing or adding
        delete this.body[name];
    else
        this.body[name] = { $in: para };
}

onFilterReceived(para: any, type: string) {
    if (type == 'lan') {
        this.processType('languages.primary', para);
    }
    if (type == 'zip') {
        this.processType('zipCode', para);
    }
    if (type == 'nat') {
        this.processType('services.service', para);
    }
    console.log(this.body);

    this.filtersService.getByFilter(this.page, this.pagesize, this.body)
        .subscribe(resRecordsData => {
                       this.records = resRecordsData;
                   },
                   responseRecordsError => this.errorMsg = responseRecordsError
        );
}
```

Comment: Looking at this code, I still think the issue is that the "if" statements are only going to let me handle passing one filter at a time. Right? Also, I think "body" would need to be "this.body" in the above occurrences.

Comment: Also, I am simplifying in my code above. But I actually have four filters running - not just two. So a pure either/or option won't work.

Comment: body is moved to your component class. Filter will be stacked and unstacked as it is not a local variable anymore.

Comment: Okay. Let me try it out.

Comment: Okay, I plugged in the code. This is what happens: On the "language" filter, if I check "Spanish" - the data filters for that, as expected. If I then move to the "zip" filter, and filter for that, I get results that filter for zip, but the language filter selection is lost. So still getting one or the other filter, not both.

Comment: When I look at the network tab, the payload also shows this. If my last selection was "Spanish" within the "language" tab, I see:

{services.workflow.status: "intake", languages.primary: {$in: ["Spanish"]}}
languages.primary
:
{$in: ["Spanish"]}

Notice the "zip" filter selection is not there in the payload. Still one or the other.

Comment: Can you print out this.body?

Comment: Hold on. I see you have two functions now. Let me refactor.

Comment: Wow! I think that's it. I'm now seeing both filters being processed in the same call. And the data filtering shows that in the view as well. Much appreciated, @wannadream!